# How to make a circle with a number perfectly centered?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a circle with a number perfectly centered inside.  As you can see from the example below, it's pretty close.

However, number 42 slightly tilts to the right, so do numbers 11 and 12.  However, 62 and 92 are fine.  What am I missing?  Does it have to do with the font?

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.number {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.status-past-due {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}

.status-due-today {
  background-color: #6FA8DC;
}

.status-future {
  background-color: #93C47D;
}

.status-completed {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.status-all {
  background-color: white;
}

.circle:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.circle:active {
    width: 24px; 
    height: 24px;
    border: 4px solid gray;    
}

.circle-selected {
    width: 24px; 
    height: 24px;
    border: 4px solid gray;    
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-selected status-past-due" title="Reminders Past Due">
    <span class="number">42</span> 
</div>

<div class="circle status-due-today" title="Reminders Past Due">
    <span class="number">12</span> 
</div>

<div class="circle status-future" title="Reminders Past Due">
    <span class="number">11</span> 
</div>

<div class="circle status-completed" title="Reminders Past Due">
    <span class="number">62</span> 
</div>

<div class="circle status-all" title="Reminders Past Due">
    <span class="number">92</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: consider a monospace font

Comment: You can try font-family:monospace. I don't know if its still a browser issue but I know at some point **font-family: monospace, monospace;** had to be used

Comment: This might be a visual illusion. The center of the number might be in the center of the circle, but because the different corners of the different numbers land in a variable distance from the circle’s edge, they might appear to be off center

Comment: In addition to monospace, maybe your font supports tabular number styles, which will help with the appearance seeming off center: font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried your suggestion and that does work.  ChatGPT suggests this font family so that it looks legit on Windows, Mac, iOS and Android: `font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono WT", "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "DejaVu Sans Mono", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Liberation Mono", "Nimbus Mono L", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;`

Comment: @RúnarBerg Oh `tabular-nums` is pretty cool - never heard of it.  I think this might be the ticket.

Comment: ㊷ ⑪ ⑫ :), I don't know if you can do arbitrarily large numbers like this though. I've only seen up to 50 on one site: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_circled_numbers.html Unicode's own charts only show to 20: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can these fonts be made to have arbitrary fill and border colors?  And borders of varying thickness?

Comment: If you mean that the two characters should appear to have the same distance between them and their closest edge of the circle horizontally, no amount of using monospace or tabular-nums is going to achieve it for every typeface. This is mainly, but not only, because of the skinniness of the digit 1. The only way I've found a general solution is to paint the characters on a canvas and find the extremities of each one. Even then it can sometimes appear not perfect (e.g. because of a long top serif on the 1) but may be the nearest you can get without doing it yourself for each combination by eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably overflowing the container which you set to `24px`.

You can use [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content) to make sure the container always fits the content. And then [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) to make sure the container stays a perfect square:

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  line-height: 1em;
  min-width: 1em;
  width: max-content;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.number {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-selected status-past-due" title="Reminders Past Due">
  <span class="number">42</span>
</div>

<div class="circle status-due-today" title="Reminders Past Due">
  <span class="number">12</span>
</div>

<div class="circle status-future" title="Reminders Past Due">
  <span class="number">11</span>
</div>

<div class="circle status-completed" title="Reminders Past Due">
  <span class="number">62</span>
</div>

<div class="circle status-all" title="Reminders Past Due">
  <span class="number">92</span>
</div>
```

Also worth pointing out is [`font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric) to make your numbers somewhat uniform in width and might help with keeping the numbers from *appearing* off center even though they are centered.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why are the circles elongated now?

Comment: aspect-ratio: 1 / 1 should fix that... I might have had a type-o in the original answer... edited.

Comment: aspect-ratio doesn’t seem to have fixed it. Does it work with width set to max-content?

Comment: You might still have height set to 24px (or 30px) if so, aspect-ratio will have no effect (or rather, the width may be determined by the height). you must unset height for it to work. Or perhaps your browser doesn’t support aspect-ratio

Comment: I’m testing on iOS Safari 16+ which supports aspect ratio and am seeing differently stretched circles. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I’m using firefox on Ubuntu. The sizes of the squares are actually different in my browser, but they are all square. If you want them to be the same, then you need to use a grid layout

Comment: Oh, actually the if the max-content width is less then the line height the circles will actually get squished, this may happen with different font. I will fix the answer

Comment: The stretched circles are all now proper circles but the 12 still looks off center as is to be expected given how thin a 1 is compared to the other digits.